# get a property's private setter within inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection, properties

following are my codes:

```
class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; private set; }
}
```

and

```
var prop = typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Bar");
if (prop != null)
{
    // The property exists
    var setter = prop.GetSetMethod(true);
    if (setter != null)
    {
        // There's a setter
        Console.WriteLine(setter.IsPublic);
    }
}
```

yes, as you can imagine, this works perfectly right. but when there comes a inheritance, things are different:

```
class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; private set; }
}

class A : Foo
{ 

}
```

of course i changed this line:

```
var prop = typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Bar");
```

to

```
var prop = typeof(A).GetProperty("Bar");
```

then, the setter gets to null, and console print nothing!

so...why?

btw, is there some workaround to make this happen or totally another way to?

any help would be appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so...why?

As far as `A` is concerned, `Bar` is read-only - you can't call the setter from `A`, so it does make sense that there's no setter when you ask for the property with respect to `A`.

One alternative is to use binding flags to only ask for *declared* properties - and walk your way up the inheritance chain until you find the actual property declaration. It's a little bit odd that you have to do this, but it does make a certain amount of sense, as the property really *is* different depending on whether you're coming to it from the context of the declaring class or not.

I'm *surprised* by this behaviour - but not *shocked*.

Answer (score 3):

The general solution is to call

```
var prop = GetType().GetProperty("Bar").DeclaringType.GetProperty("Bar");
```

Which is not very intuitive, i agree.

Comment: maybe you need a recursion here. the hierarchy could be any possible.

Comment: no, unless you use `new` operator at some level of your hierarchy, you shoud always get `typeof(Foo)` when calling `DeclaringType` for `Bar` property. Actually even if you use `new` it might work.

Comment: i write some code to proving and yes you are right. but, when i use 'new' operator, the DeclaringType was not the typeof(Foo) again, it`s typeof(A), below was my code(just the hierarchy):                  `class Foo
    {
        public string Bar { get; private set; }
    }

    class A : Foo
    {
        public new string Bar { get; private set; }
    }

    class B : A
    { 
        
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the private property with reflection by just using the SetValue method in the property info, even if you can't get the set method.